# MPI parallel runing a parallel program

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have the following doubts, I am developing a genetic algorithm that uses a second program to do certain calculations. This second program is implemented parallelization.

My program calls this second program to do the necessary calculations. With MPI, I can run two calculations at the same time.

But I would like to implement a way to run these same calculations using also parallelizing own program. a simple scheme below

```
                                         GENETIC
                                            |
                                            |       ---> MPI HERE
                                           / \
                                          /   \
                                         /     \
                       1º machine - PROGRAM    PROGRAM - 2º machine
                                     /\         /\
                                    /  \       /  \
                                   /    \     /    \
                            program paralell   program paralell
```

That is, I reserve the MPI 6 cores on 2 machines, 3 on each machine to run my genetic algorithm, in each of these machines I share the task called 2x the second program, 1 on each machine and each machine the second program will do the calculations using 3 cores.

Sorry for my English, I did my maximum to explain in a simple way, if you still have any questions about the process I try to explain in a different way ...

Comment: What is your question ?  I think your explanation of what you want to do is clear, and it is certainly possible to do what you propose with MPI.  But what do you want us to tell you ?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you're doing now, and what you wish you could do?   It's not quite clear to me how GENETIC launches PROGRAM just now; and that obviously effects what you'd have to change to get it to launch PROGRAM differently.

Comment: my program is just the genetic algorithm, for the certain properties of my population I need a second program. In the code i call this second program to perform this calculation. i'm currently making each individual is calculated in a different core. But this second program has an option to parallelize  the computation of this property. So a want each individual is allocated to different machines in a cluster